# Using QuartzCore to draw a border around UIView results in border being 1 px smaller than the view;

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, quartz-core

I tried to draw a custom view with following code, but border for some reason renders incorrectly with small gap at the top.

```
    self.infoContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, (self.contentImage.image.size.height/self.contentImage.image.size.width)*320.0-50), self.view.frame.size.width - 24, self.view.frame.size.height - self.contentImage.frame.size.height - 24)];
    self.infoContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.infoContainerView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    self.infoContainerView.layer.borderColor = [[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.15f] CGColor];
```

And this is the result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLHs5.png]

Answer (score 0):

try giving border color like

```
self.infoContainerView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: try changing the borderWidth to 1.0f

Comment: I tried that too, whatever the width is, e.g. 5.0f, its still there :/

Comment: In the image border color is not black color [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor] this would resolve the issue

Comment: Replace your first line by this   self.infoContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 24, self.view.frame.size.height - self.contentImage.frame.size.height - 24)]; If you have white background view you can get the issue

Comment: I actually found out what the issue was. My y coordinate in code is given by (self.contentImage.image.size.height/self.contentImage.image.size.width)*320-50). The problem fixed itself when i used ceilf() on it.